# Configure Hibernate 5.2 for Spring Boot 1.4.3

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Currently I am trying to upgrade my Spring boot app to use Hibernate 5.2, curently spring boot automatically uses 5.0 with the JPA.  I want 5.2 for better support of Java 8 time objects.  I havent found a clear way , what dependencies I need to add to my gradle.build file, these are the ones associated with data:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'HikariCP', version: '2.6.1'
```

Application properties:

```
#first db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost/nuid
spring.datasource.username = nuid
spring.datasource.password = nuid
spring.datasource.type = com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query = SELECT 1
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle = 1
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size = 5
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name = nonUserPool

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy = 
org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl

# General JPA properties
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false

# Hibernate Specific properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Comment: Ended up finding a solution very simple just add this to the build.gradle:

    ext['hibernate.version'] = '5.2.10.Final'
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.10.Final')